# Passing variable from Partial View to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am dynamically inserting a Markdown editor in Partial view based on the id passed to the Partial View.

```
 @Html.Partial("_MarkdownEditor", new { id = "editorsection" })

    var @ViewData.Eval("id")  = new tui.Editor({
    el: document.querySelector('#@ViewData.Eval("id")')
```

The problem is i can't access the `@ViewData.Eval("id")` in other Javascript file.

```
<%=@ViewData.Eval("id")%>.importManager.eventManager.emit('command', 'AddImage')
```

This doesn't work Javascript takes that as a String and doesn't evaluate to 'editorsection'
So i tried something like `var editor ='<%=@ViewData.Eval("id")%>'` and then

```
editor.importManager.eventManager.emit('command', 'AddImage')
```

Same here it takes as a String !!
How to achieve this ? Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I did not understand your code, but as per the question in your post.

I would approach it as below,
In Partial View

```
 <input type="hidden" id="hf-org-id" value="@ViewBag.OrganizationId" />
```

And in javascript/jQuery

```
var orgId = $("#hf-org-id").val();
```